java ThreadPoolExecutor with SynchronousQueue rejects task, how to avoid this
How can I make sure that the previous task is completely done, and the worker thread is ready to accept a new task.
Such code rejects the second task on some computers:
ThreadPoolExecutor exe = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
Future future = exe.submit(task1);
while (!future.isDone()) {
        //do something, wait for result
        sleep(1);
}
Future future = exe.submit(task2); // Sometimes it rejects the task

I saw a similar question, but it's not solved (ThreadPoolExecutor mysteriously rejecting runnables).
UPD: stack trace
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService$QueueingFuture@8c1e52e[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@6cdbdc4f[Wrapped task = java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2aa7cf9b[Not completed, task = com.my.example.DatabaseValue$$Lambda$1438/0x0000000840650440@6c918fb6]]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3aca79dd[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 592]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.submit(ExecutorCompletionService.java:184)
...

I have no luck to reproduce it on my computers, but it happens on others.
UPD2: Workaround
Now instead of SynchronousQueue I have to use LinkedBlockingQueue(1). Now thread pool can submit 2 tasks, the first is active, the second is queued. To protect my code from double submit I control active tasks overriding ThreadPoolExecutor.beforeExecute, ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute and checking that there are no active tasks before calling submit.

I assume this is just for demonstration purposes, because using a ThreadPoolExecutor and then blocking the initial thread to wait for it to complete sounds a bit counterproductive: then why not just run the task on your current thread?

You could also try creating the executor with ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.

@MarkRotteveel the main thread is doing its work, not just waiting for the task to complete.

@MarkRotteveel I'll try ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy, thank you.

This use case seems odd. You commented below on an answer: "The program flow should be: submit task, get value, submit task, get value, ..." The flow is then: 1. Main thread creates a separate worker thread, 2. main thread blocks until that separate thread is finished, 3. main thread proceeds by creating another thread, then 4. main thread blocks until 2nd worker is done. This approach looks overly complicated, and could simply be: main thread calls a method, wait for that method to finish, main thread calls second method, etc., so: skip executors, futures, threads, etc. What are we missing?

@Kaan between each "submit task" and "get value" there is a loop, this loop does some work while waiting. In that answer I meant no two submits without a get between.

To ensure that the task is completed, you can use the Future.get() method. It is used to get the result of an asynchronous operation. It blocks execution until the result is available.
Future.isDone() == true, means only that the task corresponding to this Future is finished, but it does not mean that the pool is ready to take a new task. You have one thread running in the pool and there is no room for tasks to wait. Therefore, a situation may arise when the thread has already finished working on the current task, but is not yet ready to take a new task. In such a situation, you will get a RejectedExecutionException error.
There is no way to know when a thread is ready to take on a new task.

I have a different problem, I can get value from the task, but I cannot submit a new task.

@XorNut I can't reproduce your problem. Please attach a stack trace of the error to clarify the situation.

the post updated with stack trace.

@XorNut Future.isDone() == true, means only that the task corresponding to this Future is finished, but it does not mean that the pool is ready to take a new task. You have one thread running in the pool and there is no room for tasks to wait. Therefore, a situation may arise when the thread has already finished working on the current task, but is not yet ready to take a new task. In such a situation, you will get a RejectedExecutionException error.

I know this, my post starts with this. I do not know how to deal with this.

@XorNut There is no way to know when a thread is ready to take on a new task.

Increase max pool size to allow more threads and adjust keepAliveTime for idle threads.

I do not need more threads, I need only one worker thread and I use SynchronousQueue to reject multiple submit. The program flow should be: submit task, get value, submit task, get value, ...

Your question is written specifically about ThreadPoolExecutors and Futures, but the problem you're trying to solve does not include any details which require that.
In the comments above, you clarified:

between each "submit task" and "get value" there is a loop, this loop does some work while waiting. In that answer I meant no two submits without a get between

So, your actual problem statement looks like:

There's a main thread
There's a work task, let's call it Task 1, which is launched by the main thread
While Task 1 is running, the main thread has other work to do.
When both the main thread work and Task 1 are complete, the main thread should start a new task, let's call it Task 2

To solve such a problem, I would use a CountDownLatch as the coordination mechanism between the main thread and the two separate worker threads.

Here's the first sentence from Javadoc for CountDownLatch:

A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.


The main thread needs to:

Create Task 1 and start it running
Do whatever separate work – doSeparateWorkOnMainThread() for this example
When main thread is finished with separate work, it needs to be sure Task 1 is finished before proceeding, so it will call latch.await().
Once the latch allows the main thread to proceed, it needs to reset the latch and create Task 2 (and once again wait for it with latch.await()).

Here's an example showing how to do that:
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Task("Task 1", latch).start();   // start a thread, give it the latch

    doSeparateWorkOnMainThread();
    latch.await();

    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);             // reset the latch
    new Task("Task 2", latch).start();   // start next thread using the new latch

    latch.await();  // wait for the latch
    System.out.printf("%s: done%n", System.currentTimeMillis());
}


Here's the method for the main thread to do some work. All this does is Thread.sleep() for 1 second or less and print some stuff.
private static void doSeparateWorkOnMainThread() throws InterruptedException {
    long millisToSleep = (long) (Math.random() * 1000L);
    System.out.printf("%s: Main thread starting separate work (%s milliseconds)%n",
            System.currentTimeMillis(), millisToSleep);
    Thread.sleep(millisToSleep);
    System.out.printf("%s:    > Main thread separate work finished%n",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
}


The last part of the example is the Task class:

Task is a simple thread class, interesting only in that it uses a CountDownLatch
It calls Thread.sleep() to pause somewhere between 1 and 2 seconds (your real thread can do whatever actual work, and take however long it needs to take)
At the end, it calls countDown() which "Decrements the count of the latch, releasing all waiting threads if the count reaches zero". Since the latch was created with initial count of 1 – new CountDownLatch(1) – then the count will be 0 after calling latch.countDown() and the waiting threads (the main thread in this example) will be released. This is how Task 1 coordinates with the main thread to signal that it's done.

Here's example code:
static class Task extends Thread {
    private final String name;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public Task(String name, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            long millisToSleep = (long) (Math.random() * 1000L) + 1000L;
            System.out.printf("%s: %s starting (%s milliseconds)%n",
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), this.name, millisToSleep);
            Thread.sleep(millisToSleep);
            System.out.printf("%s:    > %s finished%n",
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), this.name);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            // always decrement the latch when finished
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}


If you run it, you'll see output like this:
1728443526303: Main thread starting separate work (238 milliseconds)
1728443526303: Task 1 starting (1683 milliseconds)
1728443526551:    > Main thread separate work finished
1728443527996:    > Task 1 finished
1728443527997: Task 2 starting (1362 milliseconds)
1728443529365:    > Task 2 finished
1728443529366: done

You'll note that this solution doesn't require queues, executors, futures, or any of the additional checks or policies mentioned in the comments.
If you want to extend behavior so that multiple task threads can run concurrently, the main thread can simply use 2 (or more) when creating the CountDownLatch and start() as many threads as makes sense before calling latch.await().
